# Python: Drop Column from DataFrame Multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have the following DataFrame:

```
data_raw (201 x 600)
Column Level 0: ROE_1 ROE_2 Test_EQ_1
Column Level 1: A B C D E F G H I J .... (200 items)
Index Level 0: 1 2 3 4... (201 items)
```

I am trying to drop the `Test_EQ_1` column.

After using:

```
data_raw = data_raw.drop("Test_EQ_1", axis=1, level=0)
```

The dataframe's dimension is reduced to 201x400 (as expected). All columns with `Test_EQ_1` are gone (as expected).

However, when I use the following:

```
data_raw.columns.levels[0]
```

I obtain:

```
Index(['ROE_1', 'ROE_2', **'Test_EQ_1'**], dtype='object', name='Variable')
```

This is generating issues for later parts of my code, as `Test_EQ_1` is gone from the dataframe, but still present when I check the columns.

Is there a way to "completely" delete `Test_EQ_1`?

Answer (score 2):

Found an answer: Redefine the columns:

```
    multi = data_raw.columns.to_list()
    data_raw.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(multi)
```